# How can I justify these three divs on a single line, one to the left, one in the centre, and one to the right?

Tags: html, css, flexbox, alignment

I would like to display three elements on a single line: one justified to the left; the second in the centre and containing sub-elements; and the third justified to the right and containing a DuckDuckGo search box and a magnifying glass image. At the moment I have got them all on the same line but they aren't justifying properly. My code is as follows:

```css
#row2 { padding: 5px 0 5px 10px;
margin: 35px 0 20px 0;
font-size: 83%;
width: 100%;
border-top: 2px #f00 solid;
border-bottom: 1px #888 solid; }

#row2 a {border: none; }

#row2-col1 {display:inline;
text-align:left;
margin-right: 40px;}

#row2-col2 {display:inline;
text-align:center; }

.row2-col2-inner {display:inline;
text-align:center;
margin: 0 15px;  }

#row2-col3 {display:inline;
text-align:right; }

form {
display: inline-block;
vertical-align: middle; }

form input[type="text"] {
height: 16px;
width: 200px;
margin-left: 25px;
margin-top: 2px;
font-size: 13px;
-webkit-border-radius: 5px;
-moz-border-radius: 5px;
border-radius: 5px;
border: 1px solid #000;
vertical-align: top; }
```

```html
<div id="row2">
<div id="row2-col1">
text</div><!--close r2-c1-->
<div id="row2-col2">
<div class="row2-col2-inner"><a href="#3">One</a></div>
<div class="row2-col2-inner"><a href="#4">Two</a></div>
<div class="row2-col2-inner"><a href="#5">Three</a></div>
<div class="row2-col2-inner"><a href="#6">Four</a></div>
</div><!--close r2-c2-->
<div id="row2-col3">
<form method="get" id="search" action="http://duckduckgo.com/">
<input type="hidden" name="sites" value="foobar.com"/>
<input type="hidden" name="k8" value="#000000"/>
<input type="hidden" name="k9" value="#0000ff"/>
<input type="hidden" name="kaa" value="#880088"/>
<input type="hidden" name="kt" value="a"/>
    <input type="text" name="q" maxlength="255" placeholder="&nbsp;..."/>             

&nbsp;<img src="images/image.gif" height="20" width="20">
</form>
</div><!--close r2-c3-->
</div><!--close row2-->
```

Answer (score 1):

There are a hundred different ways to accomplish what you're trying to do:

1. Floats (Easy)
2. Flexbox (Advanced)
3. Display (which you are attempting by the looks of it)
4. Absolute positioning (Weird, but applicable in some situations)

... and so on ...

Based on your example code I would keep it simple and use floats. Also, IMO, you should stay away from using ids - use classes instead.

In the below example I will assume you want 25%-50%-25%. The simple structure being:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="column left">Left side</div>
    <div class="column center">Center column</div>
    <div class="column right">Right</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
/* overflow and zoom are just to clear the row */
http://learnlayout.com/clearfix.html

.row {
    overflow: auto;
    zoom: 1;
}

.row .column {
    float: left;
}

/* set the width of each column */
.column.left, .column.right {
    width: 25%;
}

.column.center {
    width: 50%;
}
```

#### Note:

- This would not account for padding. If you want spacing between the columns then have the inner contents handle that with padding or margins.
- This is a specific example to your situation
- Nowadays it is quite common to use frameworks for grids. They give you a lot more options and are tried and tested techniques that handle a lot of the edge cases. Search *css grid* and that will get you started.

Answer (score 0):

If `flexbox` is an option, you can make `row2` a *flexbox* and use `justify-content: space-between` to align as required - see demo below:

```css
#row2 {
  padding: 5px 0 5px 10px;
  margin: 35px 0 20px 0;
  font-size: 83%;
  width: 100%;
  border-top: 2px #f00 solid;
  border-bottom: 1px #888 solid;
  /*ADDED THESE*/
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

#row2 a {
  border: none;
}

#row2-col1 {
  display: inline;
  text-align: left;
  margin-right: 40px;
}

#row2-col2 {
  display: inline;
  text-align: center;
}

.row2-col2-inner {
  display: inline;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0 15px;
}

#row2-col3 {
  display: inline;
  text-align: right;
}

form {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

form input[type="text"] {
  height: 16px;
  width: 200px;
  margin-left: 25px;
  margin-top: 2px;
  font-size: 13px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
  -moz-border-radius: 5px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  vertical-align: top;
}
```

```html
<div id="row2">
  <div id="row2-col1">
    text</div>
  <!--close r2-c1-->
  <div id="row2-col2">
    <div class="row2-col2-inner"><a href="#3">One</a>
    </div>
    <div class="row2-col2-inner"><a href="#4">Two</a>
    </div>
    <div class="row2-col2-inner"><a href="#5">Three</a>
    </div>
    <div class="row2-col2-inner"><a href="#6">Four</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!--close r2-c2-->
  <div id="row2-col3">
    <form method="get" id="search" action="http://duckduckgo.com/">
      <input type="hidden" name="sites" value="foobar.com" />
      <input type="hidden" name="k8" value="#000000" />
      <input type="hidden" name="k9" value="#0000ff" />
      <input type="hidden" name="kaa" value="#880088" />
      <input type="hidden" name="kt" value="a" />
      <input type="text" name="q" maxlength="255" placeholder="&nbsp;..." />&nbsp;

      <img src="images/image.gif" height="20" width="20">
    </form>
  </div>
  <!--close r2-c3-->
</div>
<!--close row2-->
```

Comment: Many thanks - this is brilliant and does the job. But I am trying to do it without flexbox.